# Bubble sort algorithm input not working (Python)

Tags: python, input, bubble-sort

this is a question about some of the handling of arrays in python.

I have the following code that reads an array of numbers from the variable `sorted`:

```py
print("Original: ",sorted)

for largeRepeat in range(0,len(sorted)):
    for Repeat in range(0,len(sorted)-1):
        Number1 = sorted[Repeat]
        Number2 = sorted[Repeat + 1]
        if Number1 > Number2:
            sorted[Repeat] = sorted[Repeat+1]
            sorted[Repeat+1] = Number1



print("Sorted: ",sorted)
```

---

Now, the problem I have is that I can assign the array some values in 2 different ways, hard-coded into the program:

`sorted = [1,11,22,2]`

or by user input, splitting the numbers provided by using `split()`:

```py
inputs = input("Enter numbers as comma (,) separated values: ")
ToSort = inputs.split(",")
sorted = ToSort
```

---

If I use the permanent method, the program correctly returns:

```py
Original:  [1, 11, 22, 2]
Sorted:  [1, 2, 11, 22]
```

but, if I use the user input, the program incorrectly returns:

```py
Original:  ['1', '11', '22', '2']
Sorted:  ['1', '11', '2', '22']
```

---

Could anyone please provide any insight into why this might be happening, I've tried running the program multiple times and isolated it to this specific section.

I've also noticed that it returns the numbers in the user input as strings of text but I don't see how this could cause a problem. (Sorry, i'm quite new to this!)

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Thank you, this has been [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64668961/14572690)!

Comment: To be clear, user input being strings of text is a big problem because to a computer, strings are just ASCII numbers, not the value stored in the string.

Comment: @M-Chen-3, thank you, makes sense!

Comment: Just out of curiosity.  Why are you writing your own sort rather than just using Python's built-in sort?  Bubble Sort is one of the worst sort algorithms out there.  It's even slower than other O(n^2) algorithms.   Your entire code could be rewritten as `sorted.sort()`

Comment: @FrankYellin, it was a challenge set to me by someone. For educational purposes. Not work, just a challenge.

Comment: Okay.  I was scared this was a homework assignment or something, and wondering why they were teaching you the moral equivalent of rewinding a VCR or dialing a rotary phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast each input as `int`

```
ToSort = list(map(int, inputs.split(",")))
```